# Recreating an ActiveX control with VBA events, using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I have a combobox that has multiple events tied to it (eg, ComboBox1_Change, Click, GotFocus, LostFocus).  For my purposes, I need to use an ActiveX control.

For some background:

I ran into an issue where the ActiveX control glitches when the machine is attached to a projector.  Other's have had the same problem, but no solution.  The best way I found to solve this issue is to create an additional button the user can click which deletes the ActiveX control and recreate it.

The problem is (and my question)... When I do this, the VBA events no longer execute.  The control is named the exact same.  Is there a simple fix (such as property in the ActiveX control I can set), so that I do not need to write VBA code to delete and rewrite existing VBA code (which I'm not even 100% sure will fix the issue)?

Comment: To better help, could you post the existing piece of code that you're modifying?

Comment: Are the controls on a Worksheet or a UserForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me, in a worksheet:

Start with 2 CommandButtons on a worksheet: `CommandButton1` and `CommandButton2`.

You can't step through the code, but it will run.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim oldObj As OLEObject
  Dim left As Double, top As Double, width As Double, height As Double
  Set oldObj = Me.OLEObjects("CommandButton2")

  With oldObj
    'Rename the control to detach events
    .Name = "CommandTEMP"
    left = .left
    top = .top
    width = .width
    height = .height
    .Delete
  End With

  Dim newObj As Object

  Set newObj = Me.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
        , DisplayAsIcon:=False, left:=left, top:=top, width:=width, height:=height)

  newObj.Name = "CommandButton2"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  Me.CommandButton2.Object.Caption = Timer
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be working, with one added issue... now anytime I click on the combobox, the screen "twitches", and the cursor jobs somewhere else.  No VBA events are being triggered, since I put breakpoints on every module.  After this happens, I can't click anywhere on the screen.  I have to alt-tab to another window, then alt tab back into Excel.

Comment: @ConfusedNoob don't be convinced that breakpoints aren't being hit. Note that I said you can't step through code after a certain point, and some breakpoints will be ignored from that point. Use `debug.print` statements to confirm code is being hit.

Comment: @ConfusedNoob Is the control on a sheet or a form?

Comment: Control is on a worksheet.  Good suggestion on the debug.print, did not think of it... I added in the debug.print to every event within my VBA code.  Nothing is triggering...

Comment: Are you perhaps in design mode?

Comment: No, not in design mode